# Sequelize query to get records not in associations

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

There are two tables userMedium and medium. medium hasMany userMedia. For a user, wanna get the medium records that not included in the userMedia. With the Sequelize library, it was implemented as:

```
const um = await Models.UserMedium.findAll({
    where: {userId},
    attributes: ['mediumId']
  }),
     media = await Models.Medium.findAll({
          where: {
            id: {
              $notIn: _.pluck(um, 'mediumId')
            }
          }
        });
```

Wonder is there a better way to run the query by using the eager loading?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the version of Sequelize that you are using supports this, but on the documentation explains [how to use eager loaded models in top level where clause](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#top-level-where-with-eagerly-loaded-models).

The following piece of code exploits eager loading and should work for you.

```
const media = await Medium.findAll({
    where: { '$UserMedium.userId$': userId },
    include: ['UserMedium']
});
```